# Fetching data from server in multiple pages of Flask application

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, sidebar

I'm using Python with Flask and Jinja2 and I'm trying to implement a sidebar. In the HTML pages I have got this:

```
{% include "sidebar.html" %}
```

What I want in the sidebar file is to have a block of the latest users. To do that I need to get the results from the server for the sidebar.html file. But where should I write the code for that in the python file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you could implement this functionality is by creating a Jinja variable on the python side:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.jinja_env.globals.update({
  'latest_users': get_latest_users()
})

def get_latest_users() {
  return ['Mark', 'Jane', 'Sally']
}
```

The variable `latest_users` can now be accessed from any Jinja template simply by doing:

```
{% for user in latest_users %}
  <p>{{ user }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Would I have to put the globals.update bit multiple times for multiple variables?

Comment: `app.jinja_env.globals.update()` takes a dictionary as it's argument, meaning that you could add multiple key value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables to the templates. When you use `include` your variables still can be used in this included part too:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    users = ['user1', 'user2']
    debug = False
    render_template('index.html', users=users, debug=debug)

# index.html
{% include "sidebar.html" %}

#sidebar.html
{% for user in users %}
  <p>{{ user }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{{debug}}
```

Comment: Will those variables in index work for the sidebar in other pages as well though?

Comment: Yes but but instead of `index.html` you should write that html file `render_template('other.html', users=users, debug=debug)`. Now if you include `sidebar.html` into `other.html` it you can use this variables `users`, `debug`